# how to remove duplicate object from array by comparing two keys in same array?

Tags: javascript

I have checked similar questions but they either remove duplicate by using a single key or its comparison between two array of object, here I have an array of object where i want to remove objects if they have same id and and same code. if p_id and c_code is same remove

```
 const arr = filter(this.campaignArr, el => {
            if (el.p_id== el.p_id && el.c_code== el.c_code) {
              return el;
            }
          });
          console.log(arr)

[{id:"1", p_id:"mobile", c_code:"aaa"},
{id:"1", p_id:"mobile", c_code:"aaa"},
{id:"2", p_id:"electronics", c_code:"aaa"},
{id:"1", p_id:"mobile", c_code:"bbb"},
{id:"2", p_id:"electronics", c_code:"bbb"},
{id:"2", p_id:"electronics", c_code:"bbb"}]
```

expected output

```
[{id:"1", p_id:"mobile", c_code:"aaa"},
{id:"2", p_id:"electronics", c_code:"aaa"},
{id:"1", p_id:"mobile", c_code:"bbb"},
{id:"2", p_id:"electronics", c_code:"bbb"}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're facing now is due to the line:

```
if (el.p_id== el.p_id && el.c_code== el.c_code)
```

Which will always hit, since `el.p_id== el.p_id && el.c_code== el.c_code` is always `true` because you're comparing the element to itself.

Instead use an [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to store and check which values you've already added. Use a JSON string as unique key. This can be achieved by [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) an array of the relevant property values.

Then return a falsy value to exclude the current item if the key is present in a set. If the key is not present, add the key to the set and return a truthy value to include the current item.

```js
const campaigns = [
  {id:"1", p_id:"mobile", c_code:"aaa"},
  {id:"1", p_id:"mobile", c_code:"aaa"},
  {id:"2", p_id:"electronics", c_code:"aaa"},
  {id:"1", p_id:"mobile", c_code:"bbb"},
  {id:"2", p_id:"electronics", c_code:"bbb"},
  {id:"2", p_id:"electronics", c_code:"bbb"}
];

const lookup = new Set();
console.log(
  campaigns.filter(campaign => {
    // stringify an array of the properties you want to use for uniqueness
    const key = JSON.stringify([campaign.p_id, campaign.c_code]);
    return !lookup.has(key) && lookup.add(key);
  })
);
```

**Note:** IE 11 returns `undefined` for `lookup.add(key)` (which is falsy instead of truthy). To make this IE 11 compatible change the line to:

```
return !lookup.has(key) && (lookup.add(key), true);
```

Alternatively you could write out the long version, which simultaneously is less cryptic.

```
if (lookup.has(key)) return false;
lookup.add(key);
return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it: filter the array then return the first result that matches using findIndex (dupes will be ignored since it only returns the first match).

```js
const campaignArr = [
  {id:"1", p_id:"mobile", c_code:"aaa"},
  {id:"1", p_id:"mobile", c_code:"aaa"},
  {id:"2", p_id:"electronics", c_code:"aaa"},
  {id:"1", p_id:"mobile", c_code:"bbb"},
  {id:"2", p_id:"electronics", c_code:"bbb"},
  {id:"2", p_id:"electronics", c_code:"bbb"}
]

const newArray = campaignArr.filter((item, index) => {
  const _item = JSON.stringify(item);
  return index === campaignArr.findIndex(obj => {
    return JSON.stringify(obj) === _item;
  });
});

console.log(newArray)
```

Comment: This has a few issues. 1 you are comparing the whole `item`, not just the properties `p_id` and `c_code`. 2 if `item` contains the properties in a different order the JSON output will be different while the `item` might be the same. Take for example `{a: 1, b: 2}` and `{b: 2, a: 1}` which both produce a different `JSON.stringify` output, but contain the same properties.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arr = [{id:"1", p_id:"mobile", c_code:"aaa"},
{id:"1", p_id:"mobile", c_code:"aaa"},
{id:"2", p_id:"electronics", c_code:"aaa"},
{id:"1", p_id:"mobile", c_code:"bbb"},
{id:"2", p_id:"electronics", c_code:"bbb"},
{id:"2", p_id:"electronics", c_code:"bbb"}]

let updatedArr =[];

arr.map((x)=>{
     if(!updatedArr.find((y)=>y.id == x.id && y.c_code == x.c_code)){
         updatedArr.push(x);
     }  
});

console.log(updatedArr);
```

Create an array, map through the existing arr and find if the object is already present in updated Array. Else, push it the object to new array. Hope this helps!

Comment: You use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) in void context. Switch to [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) if you'd like to keep the `updatedArr.push(x)` or to [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and completely remove `updatedArr.push(x)`, instead return the *if*-clause result. Resulting in `updatedArr = arr.filter(x => !updatedArr.find(y =>y.id == x.id && y.c_code == x.c_code))`

Answer (score 0):

There are other data structures you can use that will guarantee uniqueness. And can solve your problem in a much simpler way. No manual comparisons or complicated iterations. [Enter Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

```
let arr = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Blah' },
  { id: 1, name: 'Blah' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Bleh' } 
];

let map = new Map();
arr.forEach( x => map.set(x.id, x))
console.log(map.values());
```

Use whatever value is to be considered the unique 'key' and use it as the key in the map. It gives you O(1) read speeds if you know the key but you can also iterate over its values by using the `values` function to perform array-like operations (or to convert it back to an array).

### Edit 1: applied to your specific example:

```
let arr =[{id:"1", p_id:"mobile", c_code:"aaa"},
{id:"1", p_id:"mobile", c_code:"aaa"},
{id:"2", p_id:"electronics", c_code:"aaa"},
{id:"1", p_id:"mobile", c_code:"bbb"},
{id:"2", p_id:"electronics", c_code:"bbb"},
{id:"2", p_id:"electronics", c_code:"bbb"}]

let map = new Map();
arr.forEach( x => map.set(x.id + x.c_code, x)); // notice the only difference is what the "key" is in this line.
console.log(map.values());
```